# SOP vs SOIC test clips

Tags: flash, hardware, soic, sop

I'm mostly a software person, so this might be a super basic question. I wanna connect to an SOP8 flash chip. I see many recommendations for the Pomona clips, but that one is labeled SOIC8. I can't seem to find a consistent source as to if these two mean the same thing or if the SOIC8 clip will work for SOP8. Should the Pomona SOIC8 clip work on SOP8?

Comment: Welcome. Shopping questions are off-topic on this site. Use Google to search Pomona's website.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. You should compare the dimensions shown on the datasheet for the test clip to the dimensions shown in the datasheet for the flash chip.

Comment: In that case, do you have any recommendations for an SOP8 test clip? I can't seem to find any clips that are specifically for SOP8. Pretty much everything says SOIC8/SOP8, which is probably not accurate based on your answer.

Comment: Well, you should compare the dimensions in their datasheets. That's really the only answer.

Answer (score 0):

They're basically the same package...some of the tolerances are slightly different, but the clip is likely to work fine either way.  Just to be safe, you should probably buy a clip that lists both packages.